# Access to status message on android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I have trouble when I asking user status in code below:

private class StatusRequestListener implements RequestListener{

```
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        try {
            Log.d("GETTING RESPONSE", "Response: " + response.toString());
            JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);
            STATUS = json.getString("message");

        } catch (FacebookError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

What I see in log:

06-13 16:44:39.265: D/GETTING RESPONSE(1193): Response: {"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: /status","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

and

06-13 16:44:39.265: W/System.err(1193): com.facebook.android.FacebookError: Unknown path components: /status

How can I beat this trouble 7

Answer (score 0):

The Graph API user connection is called statuses, not status …

Comment: Thanks a lot!  And how can I get the last status7